# Posting to a URL with wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxhttp

Does anyone have some sample code showing how to POST to a URL using wxWidgets? The documentation and discussion forums imply that it's possible but the methods in wxHTTP are very low-level compared to what you find in .NET and scripting languages like Perl and Ruby. Do I actually have to create the HTTP request myself and send it to the server via the SocketOutputStream? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem initially and ended up using Curl instead as it's also cross platform and is very easy to use.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Atually, same here. Tried using wxHTTP and ended up using Curl. And Curl is a charm to work with...

J-O